# SQLSERVER: BCP import and encrypt columns using Database Key

Tags: sql-server, database, encryption, import, bcp

I have a large file which needs to be imported to SQL Server. File contains columns of personal information (like first_name, phone_number). Currently I'm importing the large file onto SQL Server using BCP tool. And as a next step, I'm encrypting the columns using Database Key as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    first_name VARCHAR(4000)
)

CREATE CERTIFICATE db_cert1
WITH SUBJECT = 'Encrypt PII data'; 
GO 

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY db_symkey1
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE db_cert1;
GO

BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE users
    SET first_name = CAST(EncryptByKey(KEY_GUID('db_symkey1'),[first_name]) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DELETE FROM users;
END CATCH
```

There are 100s of columns in my table and 10s of such sensitive columns which needs encryption and millions of rows. Currently it is slow (due to number of rows and VARCHAR(MAX/4000))

Is there a better way to achieve this? Does BCP offer any out of the box solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the steps followed to improve performance.

1. Created two columns for each sensitive data

   - first_name_plaintext VARCHAR(256)
   - first_name VARBINARY(308)
   - Thanks @gotqn for this
2. Added an auto incrementing id column, added a clustered index(this makes sure its already sorted) on the table and did updates in batches (like `WHERE [id] BETWEEN 1 AND 100000`).
3. Commit after each iteration (to reduce the transaction logs usage)
4. Changed the DB Recovery model to Simple (IMPORTANT)
5. Increased the DB file size
6. If there are no restrictions, you can use AES_128 encryption for key creation instead of AES_256, but our security advisor didn't allow this.

This improved the time from 3 minutes to 1:17 minutes for 1 million records.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are preforming cast to `nvarchar(max)` because of your fields type. It will be better, to use `varbinary` instead.

The function [EncryptByKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbykey-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns:

```
varbinary with a maximum size of 8,000 bytes.
```

So, storing your data in this format will remove the need of cast. Also, it will be better to use precise value for the `varbinary` length.

You can use the formula bellow, to check what's the maximum varbinary's length that `EncryptByKey` will return for specific text column:

```
60 + max_length - ((max_length + 8) % 16)
```

I often use the following script:

```
SELECT name,  60 + max_length - ((max_length + 8) % 16) 
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.securityUsers')
    AND name in ('FirstName', 'LastName', 'Gender', 'Address1', 'Address2', 'City', 'Province', 'Country')
```

For example, for `nvarchar(128)`, you will have `varbinary(308)`. You just need to have some way to know that when you are decrypting, tho cast to `nvarchar(128)` again.

Generally, try to use types with smallest possible precision and to cast to smallest possible precision, too.

You can for example to insert these data in a buffer table and then to just encrypt it and record it in the target table (without casting).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there any way to deal this in one single table? Also, the problem with having first_name as VARBINARY is that I first need to import the file as is to the user table, and the columns must be VARCHAR(because first_name in the file is plain string)..

Comment: Yes, you will need to do this in two steps. Importing the data in buffer table - then encrypting the data and inserting / updating in the target one with binary columns. Well, you can have `duplicate` columns in one table - for example, `first_name_text` and `first_name_encrypted` - move the data from the first column to the second and then `NULL` it, but it's not clear solution for me.

Comment: Will follow the latter aproach (having duplicate columns) to avoid the time consumption while transferring data from one table to another. Thanks

Comment: Let me know, if there is speed optimization and in what kind :=)

Comment: I've added the final list of steps as answer below